# How can I run programs in test folder Github Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-q-experience

I am new to GitHub/Python - please tell me how can I run programs in https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aqua/tree/master/test and its sub directories in Jupyter. I am connected to IBM Q Expereince. I am looking at class `QiskitBaseTestCase` and `unittest`.

I am reading on unittest - I see a template (sample fixture)

```
import unittest

def fun(x):
    return x + 1

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self):
        self.assertEqual(fun(3), 4)
```

For something like that including the following is sufficient in Jupyter.

```
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    unittest.main()
```

I have tried to copy the https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aqua/blob/master/test/base_test_case.py into Jupyter and start from there - it hasn't helped.

Please help - how to run the Qiskit test cases in Jupyter?

Comment: I think this is more of a python problem than a Qiskit problem, try looking on Stack Overflow for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37895781/unable-to-run-unittests-main-function-in-ipython-jupyter-notebook